# If value in a column contains both words, then create a new column and map the value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, vlookup

I have a data frame with a column name "Campaign".

If value in this column **CONTAINS** "General" and "PHD",
then, create a "Degree" column, fill in "PHD",

if "General" and "BS",
and fill in "BS",

if "General" and "MS",
and fill in "MS",

Else np.nan

My codes are not right I know but it might give you some sense of what I'm trying to do:

```
Campaign_Degree = []

for x in data['Campaign']:
if x.str.contains('General' and 'PHD'):
    data['Campaign_Degree'] == 'PHD'
    
    if x.str.contains('General' and 'BS'):
    data['Campaign_Degree'] == 'BS'
    
        if x.str.contains('General' and 'MS'):
        data['Campaign_Degree'] == 'MS'
    
else:
    data['Campaign_Degree'] == np.nan
```

Comment: What's your expected output ?  Please specify

Comment: is the criteria the max of the following list `['General', 'BS', 'MS', 'PHD']`?

Comment: @SeaBean - I updated my question! Hope it's easier to understand now.

Comment: @PabloC - the criteria is the cell contains "General" plus either "BS", "MS", or "PHD". The value in df['Campaign'] has to contain both words (not exact match).

Comment: @kalapangha I mean, you  need to select the "max degree" from `df["campaign"]`  row-wise?

Comment: @PabloC - I'm not sure. My question is more about mapping value if a cell contains both words. More like vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':["General & PHD",
                          "General & BS",
                          "General & MS",
                          "other",
                          "Brand_ABC_PHD",
                          "asGeneraldasPHDasda",
                          "BSasdasdGeneralppp"]})

df["new"] = df.col[df.col.str.contains("General")].str.extract("(PHD|BS|MS)")
```

**Output**

```
df
                   col  new
0        General & PHD  PHD
1         General & BS   BS
2         General & MS   MS
3                other  NaN
4        Brand_ABC_PHD  NaN
5  asGeneraldasPHDasda  PHD
6   BSasdasdGeneralppp   BS
```

Comment: Hey Pablo, thanks for answering! To clarify -- I have a column named Campaign and If values in Campaign contains both General and PHD (anywhere in the value), then fill in PHD in a Degree column.....same thing as MS and BS.

Comment: @kalapangha please add more (enough) cases to your question

Comment: Hi Pablo, I fixed the question! Please let me know if it's not clear and thank so much for your help!

Comment: @kalapangha it would be helpful If you tell me in which case this solution fails

Comment: I put my coding as a guideline but that's totally wrong. I hope it helps.

Comment: @kalapangha updated my answer. I hope it works

Comment: Hey Pablo, thanks so much for helping but this doesn't work since General and PHD are not not connected, so it won't be exact match. I did try .str.contains("General" & "PHD") but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @kalapangha what do you mean by "connected"? please show me an example where my answer fails

Comment: Let say these are the cell values in the Campaign column: General_ABC_PHD, General_ABC_BS, Brand_ABC_PHD, General_ABC_MS and I want to map PHD, BS, and MS to only the value in the column that contains both General and degree level, which means for row with Brand_ABC_PHD, it won't pick up PHD, so the cell will show null.

Comment: @kalapangha check it now :P

Comment: Ooooooh you da best! Thank you so much!

Comment: Enjoy your coffee!

Comment: @kalapangha :D ty